# How to create chrome like tabs with primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

There are buttons like chrome-firefox bookmarks(say "google","facebook","twitter"). What I want to do is when user clicks a button, its related tab will open. For example if user clicks google button, google tab will rendered.

I have created some tabs and binded these tab's "rendered" property. But the problem is when i close the tab, I couldn't change variable which binded to the tab's "rendered" property. For example when I open and close google tab and then click to openFacebookTab button, Google tab is also rendered with Facebook tab because renderGoogleTab still holds true.

Must I create tabs and tabview programmatically or is there an easy solution?

My view;

```
<p:commandButton value="openGoogleTab" actionListener="#{myController.openGoogle()}"/>

<p:commandButton value="openFacebookTab" actionListener="#{myController.openFacebook()}"/>

<p:tab id="googleId" closable="true" title="Google" rendered="#{myController.renderGoogleTab}"/>

<p:tab id="facebookId" closable="true" title="Facebook" rendered="#{myController.renderFacebookTab}"/>
```

My controller;

```
@Controller("myController")
@Scope("view")
public class MyController{

//some variables

openGoogle(){
renderGoogleTab = true;
}

openFacebook(){
renderFacebookTab = true; 
}


//getter and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code as follow,

```
openGoogle(){
 renderGoogleTab = true;
 renderFacebookTab = false;
}

openFacebook(){
 renderFacebookTab = true; 
 renderGoogleTab = false;
}
```

Comment: He can open all tabs at the same time. if he clicks google, googletab will open and if clicks facebook, another tab which is facebooktab will open. If he close googletab, facebooktab will remain.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best method probably, but one workaround is to place the tabs in two separate `tabView` components (as I understand you need to be able to open two tabs simultanously) and then add a tab close listener like in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewClosable.jsf). Then in the listener set the corresponding `render*Tab` properties to false.

So the jspx would be somewhat like this:

```
<p:tabView>  
    <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{myController.onGoogleClose}"/>  
    <p:tab id="googleId" closable="true" title="Google" rendered="#{myController.renderGoogleTab}"/>
</p:tabView>


<p:tabView>  
    <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{myController.onFacebookClose}"/>  
    <p:tab id="facebookId" closable="true" title="Facebook" rendered="#{myController.renderFacebookTab}"/>
</p:tabView>
```

Another approach would be to add a client side listener which invokes a server side method when the user clicks the close button.

Comment: what you mean by two seperate tabview components?